# Есть ли утечка памяти при использовании функции, возвращающей статичный массив?

Tags: c, массивы, память

Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, но я не могу разобраться. Есть функция, из которой я возвращаю созданный статический массив. Адрес этого массива я присваиваю переменной-указателю.

Если потом, в ходе исполнения программы я присвою адрес другого массива этой переменной, что случится с предыдущим массивом? Ресурсы, выделенные под него будут освобождены?

Или все статические массивы будут загружены в память в течение всего времени выполнения программы?

Вот пример функции:

```
string getBaseNumber(char num, nounGender nGender, nounCase nCase)
{
    string baseNumber;
    switch (num)
    {
        case 1:
            baseNumber = nGender == MASCULINE && (nCase == NOMINATIVE || nCase == ACCUSATIVE) ? "один" : "одн";
            break;

        case 2:
            baseNumber = "дв";
            break;

        case 3:
            baseNumber = "тр";
            break;

        case 4:
            baseNumber = "четыр";
            break;

        case 5:
            baseNumber = "пят";
            break;

        case 6:
            baseNumber = "шест";
            break;

        case 7:
            baseNumber = "сем";
            break;

        case 8:
            baseNumber = nCase == NOMINATIVE || nCase == ACCUSATIVE ? "восем" : "восьм";
            break;

        default:
            baseNumber = "девят";
            break;
    }

    return baseNumber;
}
```

string здесь - псевдоним для char* .

Comment: Вы же под словом "статический" имеете ввиду автоматический массив? Созданный на стеке? Как только Ваша функция заканчивается, все содержимое стека, которое она породила будет уничтожено. И куда же должен указывать Ваш адрес, который Вы вернете из этой функции? В итоге, это никакая не утечка памяти, это просто будет попытка обратиться к адресу памяти, по которому Вы не имеете права обращаться (скорее всего, Вам скажут что-то типа, что по этому адресу нельзя ничего читать/писать и программа должна аварийно закончиться). Если не повезет, Вы прочитаете мусор и будете думать, что программа работает

Comment: Что касается приведенного примера, то Вы возвращаете не массив, а указатель на символьную константу. А это уже немного другое дело.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения за ошибку. Возвращается указатель на автоматически созданный строковый массив. Но я проверил в отладчике - при выходе из функции массив не очищается, обращение к нему не вызывает ошибок.

Comment: То есть, этот пример не описывает ситуацию? Не пытайтесь вернуть указатель на автоматическую переменную. Вернуть можете динамический массив. Или массив можете передать в функцию как параметр для изменения.

Comment: @Vladimir
Как компилятор интерпретирует инструкцию вида `char* var = "some text"`?
Для "some text" создается массив char в куче в момент запуска программы, указатель на который присваивается переменной var в момент выполнения инструкции, или он создается на стеке в момент входа  в функцию и удаляется при выходе из неё?

Comment: `char* var = "some text"` - это указатель на символьную константу (вроде, по умному в литературе называют "строковый литерал"). Это никакой не массив. Храниться такая сущность может в разных местах (говорят, в зависимости от архитектуры, это может быть там же, где и код программы, а может быть в отдельной текстовой секция с доступом только на чтение).   Т.е. в итоге по вопросу - никакой массив здесь не создается. Вы возвращаете указатель на строковый литерал, который лежит *где-то*.

Comment: И если Вам надо значение такой "строки" поместить в настоящий массив символов, то делать это нужно либо библиотечной функцией копирования (типа, `strcpy()`, `strncpy()`), либо ручками копировать в цикле посимвольно (но это грубо и не по-европейски :-) ).

Comment: @Vladimir
Огромное Вам спасибо! Почитал про строковые литералы - да, это именно то, что вызывало вопросы.

Comment: Прошу прощения, немного ввел в заблуждение: "это указатель на символьную константу", конечно же, надо читать как "строковую константу". Это когда руки пишут быстрее, чем успеваешь сформулировать мысль...

Comment: Утечки не будет.  Все статические массивы загружены в память в течение всего времени выполнения программы. В вашем случае такой массив называют *строковый литерал* (обычно они располагаются в памяти, доступной только по чтению)

Comment: @Vladimir О копировании - ну почему же, вполне работает и инициализация: `char var[] = "some text";`

Comment: @Harry, конечно работает. Но только один раз в одной функции для одного массива. Да и вернуть такой массив из функции будет немножко сложно (я же ориентировался на изначальную постановку вопроса) :-).